# React Context Provider doesn't correct see state from useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have a context provider shown below for my react app. I'm exposing the 'addNewLocation' function to consumers to be able to call. I want this function to only add a new location if it doesn't already exist in state.tripList. The function works fine to update the state except for the line that checks what is in state.tripList. I added console.log and it sees the array as empty every time, even when React Dev tools tell me otherwise.

Thanks in advance if you have some thoughts. I just want to be able to see state.

```
export const TripContext = createContext();

// This context provider is passed to any component requiring the context
export const TripProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // Function to add a new location to the state above
  const addNewLocation = (location) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(state.tripList)); // debugging, tripList always is seen as empty
    /* IF THERES ALREADY THE LOCATION IN STATE, I DON'T WANT TO ADD IT */
    if (!state.tripList.includes(location)) { // This line never returns false, it always sees tripList as empty
      setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        tripList: [...prevState.tripList, ...[location]]
      }));
    }
  }

  // User passes a location, remove it
  const removeLocation = (location) => {

  }

  const initState = {
    tripList: [],
    addNewLocation: addNewLocation,
  }

  // create state (with initial value initState) and a function to update it
  const [state, setState] = useState(initState)

  return (
    <TripContext.Provider
      value={state}
    >
      {children}
    </TripContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Everything seems good, try to edit with a minimal reproducable example. Also, doing `...[location]` is the same as just using `location`

Answer (score 1):

You have enclosed your initial `tripList` state (`[]`) in the `addNewLocation` and then doubled down on enclosing the callback also into state. This means you have stale state; always updating from the same "previous" state.

The value for the context should be the `tripList` state and *just* a reference to the non-enclosed callback. Don't store the callback in local component state.

```
const TripProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // Function to add a new location to the state above
  const addNewLocation = (location) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(tripList)); // debugging, tripList always is seen as empty
    if (!tripList.includes(location)) {
      setTripList((tripList) => [...tripList, location]);
    }
  };

  // User passes a location, remove it
  const removeLocation = (location) => {};

  // create state (with initial value initState) and a function to update it
  const [tripList, setTripList] = useState([]);

  return (
    <TripContext.Provider
      value={{
        tripList, // <-- state value
        addNewLocation // <-- update callback
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </TripContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-context-provider-doesnt-correct-see-state-from-usestate]